# How to save state before application crashed in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to manage core (crash) in my application which is writen in c++. When it crashed (or before) i want to save the state so in the next start it will not start from the beginning i wan't to continue just after where it stopped. Using file to save the state will consume alot of time as i may have alot of states update per second which is not acceptable by our client. Is there any other ways to save the state (ie. SharedMemory, Enviroment variable, ...) which will not decrease so much the latency of my application?

Here is a simulation of my application:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int initial_value = 0; //TODO: LOAD INDEX VALUE

    for(int index=initial_value;index<1000000000;index++)
    {
        //TODO: SAVE INDEX VALUE
        if(index==15566164)
        {
            std::cout<<"Simulating crash"<<std::endl;
            char* invalid_address=0;
            invalid_address[0] = 0; // CORE
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"DONE"<<std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
Simulating crash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Resuming an application after it crashed is very complex and doesn't make a lot of sense. Why does you application need to crash in the first place?

Comment: _"... so in the next start it will not start from the beginning..."_ if you could do this the program would restore to the crash point and crash again - repeat.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not necessarily. A crash can have external causes.

Comment: start the worker loop in an own process and check for termination from the main program. Last index could be stored in shared memory then.

Comment: @mcilloni It's a security issue to prevent sending duplicated data to our client. And in case we had a crash we can just skip the statement and continue with the next.

Comment: @RichardCritten we will not continue from the last we will continue from last + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std::signal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) to run a custom function when SIGSEGV is emitted, just before the program ends. Keep your data in a globally accessible structure and save it within this custom function.

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct GlobalState {
    static std::vector<int> results;
    
    // Save everything from 'results' into a file or something
    static void saveState();
    // Load previous results from a file into 'results'
    static void loadState();

    static void sigHandler(int signal) {
        saveState();
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    // Setup your signal handler
    std::signal(SIGSEGV, GlobalState::sigHandler);
    // Load previous work
    GlobalState::loadState();

    // Some code that might cause a segfault here
    ...
    GlobalState::results.push_back(...);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Of course the program above should be launched by a 2nd program, whose only job is to keep launching the 1st one as long as it doesn't return a `0` error code.